# Can I know is there limited time when cache is erased in device?

Tags: ios, swift

As we all know that, iOs cache data from static url when device is called more than twice to same api. That's good practice for us. But problem is I want to know when those cached data is erased within any limited time?

Comment: Buddy yesterday someone asking nearly equal doubt https://stackoverflow.com/q/48623103/4294543

Comment: you can be sure in one thing only: the cache directory is not going to be emptied until your application uses it (=runs in any mode), everything else should be considered as a black-box – while the cached runtime objects in the memory could be removed as preemptive memory warnings.